# SharePoint workflow support?

Tags: windows-server-2008, sharepoint-2007

I am using SharePoint 2007 Enterprise + Publishing portal template + Windows Server 2008. I want to know any built-in types of workflow -- which  could be implemented by configuration without programming which is supported?

BTW: through tools like InfoPath are fine. I just want to save programming efforts to maintain code.

thanks in advance,
George

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few built-in workflows.

[Approval](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointserver/HA101544251033.aspx)

[Three-State](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointtechnology/HA101544311033.aspx)

[Collect Signatures](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointserver/HA101544281033.aspx)

[Collect Feedback](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointserver/HA101544261033.aspx)
 and

[Disposition Approval](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointserver/HA101544291033.aspx)

You didn't really say what you were looking to do, so for now, here are the built-in workflows for MOSS 2007.

Comment: Cool, question answered!

Answer (score 1):

Check the Codeplex site for more stuff from the community.  There are lots of folks working on some cool stuff for SharePoint.  Lots of great tools as well.

http://www.codeplex.com/site/search?projectSearchText=SharePoint%202007&sortBy=Relevance&tagName=%2cSharePoint%202007%2c&licenses=|&refinedSearch=true

Comment: I am confused, is your reply related to my question?